# Линковка статической библиотеки построенной в VS200x с проектом на VS2015

Tags: qt5, visual-studio-2015, lib, static

Привет всем!

Есть статическая либа (сбилженная в древней студии), есть проект Qt5.8 c выбранным китом MS2015 32 bit. При попытке сбилдить все вместе появляются ошибки линкера, вот типовые представители:

```
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl std::operator+<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,char const *)" (__imp_??$?HDU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@ABV10@PBD@Z)
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::substr(unsigned int,unsigned int)const " (__imp_?substr@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBE?AV12@II@Z)
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned int const std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::npos" (__imp_?npos@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@2IB)
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _sscanf
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _snprintf
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __vsnprintf
```

Перекопал много интернета, как понял это из-за разных CRT библиотек, но картинка не складывается как можно победить проблему в этом случае или можно ли вообще.
Может кто-то сталкивался, или может есть качественная литература по этому поводу или ссылка.

Спасибо.

ПС. Исходников либы нет, перебилдить не смогу.

Comment: Никак. Между версиями компилятора меняется бинарный стандарт. Так что если вдруг и скомпилируется, ждите неожиданных вылетов на ровном месте.

Comment: часть проблем исправится, если добавить в список либ "legacy_stdio_definitions.lib"